# Python resample function not resampling

Tags: python, pandas, finance, beta

I'm trying to resample the data, however, it does not seem to be working properly. I want to have start-of-month data to start-of-month.

The code is the following

```
df = pd.read_csv('OSEBX_daily.csv')
df = data[['time', 'OSEBX GR']]

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.normalize()
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.resample('1M').mean()
df['returns'] = df['OSEBX GR'].pct_change()
plt.plot(df['returns'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget assign back:

```
df = df.resample('1M').mean()
```